# Open-source утилиты для 3G модемов на Cи

Tags: c, модемы, 3g, opensource

Здравствуйте.

Какие существуют в природе библиотеки/приложения с открытым исходным кодом на Си (и в добавок кросс-платформенные), позволяющие управлять соединениями/получать данные с 3G-модемов?

Появилась задача написать кастомный менеждер соединений для модемов - вот ищу с чего начать. Хотелось бы услышать отзывы кто чем пользовался.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь gnokii

Comment: Насколько знаю, у него несколько ограниченный набор поддерживаемых моделей и плагинов для остальных не наблюдается.